# Inorder binary non-sorted tree traversal

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Does inorder tree traversal on a binary integer non-sorted tree produce a sorted array of integers?

I know that if it's a true binary search tree, the result is a sorted array.

For example, would this produce a sorted array:

```
6
 1
  3
4   5
 22
```

Comment: Think about it. Imagine the implications for sorting. Or just try it with the tree you gave.

Comment: It shouldn't. The reason I'm asking is because on a practice website, this array returns a sorted list. I'm thinking maybe it puts my inputs into a binary search tree before doing the inorder traversal.

Comment: You'll have to post the code that is demonstrating the problem. Also, it is considered poor form to ask a question where you know the answer, because you are really asking some other secret question. Ask the question you have.